# No crank , no start Lancer Gt 2015

Tags: ignition, mitsubishi, no-crank-no-start, lancer

2015 Mitsubishi Lancer GT wont crank from the ignition switch also , radio won’t come on and key fob isn’t working so I’m manually using the key inside to turn it .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!